# Redirection of profile pages in codeigniter using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

i have currently my user profile pages like this

www.mysite.com/profile/sohailanwarpk and htaccess rule for this is

```
RewriteRule  ^profile/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)$  /user/profile/
```

sohailanwarpk is the user name

i want to make links like this

```
www.mysite.com/sohailanwarpk
```

but the problem i am facing that i have other sites pages too.. like

```
www.mysite.com/page1

www.mysite.com/page2
```

so i can differentiate this or whats the best way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better make it by routes.php

LIKE

```
    $route['^(?!page1|page2).*'] = "user/profile";
```

Comment: ok, and how i can get sohailanwarpk from www.mysite.com/sohailanwarpk when i redirect like u mention

Comment: $route['^(?!page1|page2).*'] = "user/profile/$1";  this way you can use this

Comment: i want to compare exact page1 means i want to allow page1ss to redirect to "user/profile" how can i change above condition

Comment: $route['^(?!jobs|autos|cars).*'] = "user/profile";
i have like this if i careate autosss profile it will not work